# Do we need to synchronize java HashMap gets if there is only one writer thread and no structural modifications to the map are done

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, synchronization

In my application I need to maintain an in-memory `HashMap` that stores list of `userIds` along with their `score`.

There is one Writer Thread that updates the score of the user based on business logic. And many Reader Threads read the `score` of users from this map, ie, `map.get(userId)`.

The list of `userIds` is static, ie, no new users are added to the map.

As per JavaDoc `If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally.`

I am not making any structural changes (no additions / deletions). Do I need to use `ConcurrentHashMap` or any other `Synchronization` construct for such a use case?

Comment: Without proper synchronization, there is no guarantee that the "reading" threads will read the correct value

Comment: [Race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) will still occur but not ConcurrentModificationException will occur in your case. To investigate good concurrency practice i recommend this ressource : http://jcip.net/

Comment: you can have a map of `userId->wrapper` where wrapper contains a `volatile scrore`. simply read and write `score` would be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `map.put` operation will just update the `value` field of `HashMap$Node`. This is safe with respect to `HashMap`'s structural consistency, but there is nevertheless a data race on the `value` field. If your value type is a simple value class like `Integer`, `Long`, or `Double`, it is safe to dereference it even over a data race, but there is no guarantee that the consumer will ever see a score updated.

A clean solution to this is replacing your e.g. `Long` with `AtomicLong` as the value type. Then your map will never be updated, only its values will be mutated in a thread-safe manner.

This is the outline of solution:

1. Safely publish the map:

   ```
   volatile Map<Player, AtomicLong> scores;

   void publishScores() {
      scores = unmodifiableMap(createScoresMap());
   }
   ```
2. Update a score:

   ```
   void updateScore(Player p, long score) {
       map.get(p).set(score);
   }
   ```
3. Read a score:

   ```
   long getScore(Player p) {
      return map.get(p).get();
   }
   ```